# Can I Update my T-Mobile G1/HTC Dream so it runs Android 2

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, htc-dream

Can I Update my T-Mobile G1 (Also known as the HTC Dream) so it runs Android 2?  Is it possible to do this without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You must root your phone and install a mod such as [CyanogenMod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Dream) to get your phone running a semi-equivalent of Android 2.1+.  There is no stock rom for Android 2.1+ for the G1.  Additionally, if you do go with CyanogenMod, not all features are fully supported due to hardware limitations, such as LiveWallpapers.

Comment: +1 gotta love CyanogenMod.  I believe they support 15 devices now with CM6.

Comment: There's no need to root the phone, it's possible to flash a non-rooted image of 2.x to a phone.

Comment: @Arda Xi can you post how that works?

Answer (score 0):

You can run CyanogenMod 6.0, which is Android 2.2 aka FroYo.

A few tipps of mine: 
If you don't want it to be terrible slow, disable dithering and all effects in the settings. Maybe enable the just in time compiler (jit). 
With the app titanium backup you will be able to remove some "garbage" apps which come with the cm release which is also helpfull.

Comment: I've seen that, but you can't run havet google applications like gmail I thought

Comment: They won't come with the mod itself, but you can install the gapps package (a link is present at the installation tutorial of cm) after flashing with cm and then you'll have google apps also.